# How to replace: [text](link) with <a href="link">text</a> in java?

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I want to replace `[text](link)` with  `<a href="link">text</a>` in Java. How can I do this?

In objective-c it's look like:

```
NSRegularExpression *linkParsing = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<!\\!)\\[.*?\\]\\(\\S*\\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

**EDIT**

Finally, based on [svasa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410303/svasa) method I am did like this:

```
public String parseText(String postText) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]\\((.*)\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(postText);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(postText.length());

    while (m.find()) {
        String found_text = m.group(1);
        String found_link = m.group(2);
        String replaceWith = "<a href=" + "\"" + found_link + "\"" + ">" + found_text + "</a>";
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replaceWith);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

It's better, because used on **all** matches in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\[(.*)\\]\\((.*)\\)");
        String input = "I got  some [text](link) here";
        Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
        if( m.find() )
        {
            String found_text =  m.group(1);
            String found_link =  m.group(2);
            String replaceWith = "<a href=" + "\"" + found_link + "\"" + ">" + found_text + "</a>" ;
            input = input.replaceAll("\\[(.*)\\]\\((.*)\\)", replaceWith );
            System.out.println( input );
        }
    }
```

This will work for any "text" and any "link"

See demo [here](http://ideone.com/5U0KCU)

Comment: @insidefun consider up voting the answer, it's the SO way of "thank you":)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String string = "[text](link)";
String text = string.substring(string.indexOf("[")+1, string.indexOf("]"));
String link = string.substring(string.indexOf("(")+1, string.indexOf(")"));
String result = "<a href=\""+link+"\">"+text+"</a>";
```

or a little shorter:

```
String string = "[text](link)";
String result = "<a href=\""+string.substring(string.indexOf("(")+1, string.indexOf(")"))+"\">"+string.substring(string.indexOf("[")+1, string.indexOf("]"))+"</a>";
```

Comment: This will work if and only if string is just [text](link)